# IFTTT How to create and configure applet programmatically via API

Tags: ifttt

I am working on a project that would require every user to instantiate an existing IFTTT applet and configure it.  Rather than providing a user guide, I would like to automate the process with a wizzard but for this to work I need to figure out how to programmatically instantiate and configure applets.

Has anyone done anything similar?  Does anyone know where the documentation is?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?